# How to access generate block elements hierarchically

Tags: system-verilog

Consider code in SV interface:

```
genvar i;
generate
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) begin : g1
task ab ();
 ///< something here
endtask
end
endgenerate
```

According to LRM 1800-2012 section 27.6 I should technically be able to access this task by (consider in monitor vif is a virtual instance of interface):

```
 vif.g1[i].ab();
```

Is this correct? If yes then simulators have issue supporting it since it reports vif.g1 can't be found (elaboration time)

I've tried it without named block as well it just suppose to be:

```
vif.genblk1[i].ab();
```

but no luck.
What is the issue here? I think monitor or any other classes have handles created run time, however interface still should be static time compiled and all elements of interface should be available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a variable inside the []'s to reference the task. 
A generate loop gets flattened out at elaboration before simulation starts. So you would need to call the task with

```
   vif.g1[0].ab;
```

Here is a complete self contained example. Please try posting your questions with the same.

```
interface itf;
      for (genvar ii = 0; ii < 2; ii++) begin : g1
     task ab ();
        $display("%m");
     endtask // ab     
      end : g1
endinterface : itf
module top;
   itf i1();
   virtual itf vif;
   initial begin
      vif = i1;
      vif.g1[0].ab;
   end
endmodule : top
```

Comment: Ah even if I make sure for loop doesn't go over range of flattened / unrolled generate? It would be really lot of code if I go with plenty of task calls but I guess its a single line statement so it should be fine. Thanks for suggestion let me try that :)

Comment: The problem with accessing different generated blocks dynamically has little to do with out of range references. The problem is the genvar value can be used to define a type, which means each generated block might have a different type. A true array has all its elements the same type. For example:
 `for (genvar ii = 0; ii < 2; ii++) begin : g1
bit [i+1:0] var1;
function [ii+1:0] func;
return '1;
endfunction` each reference to var1 and func needs to have a statically determined type.

Comment: Thanks I didn't think about it :) BTW just a side note VCS (right now hopefully they will fix in future) reports feature not implemented yet, however Incisive can go through properly

Comment: Works on Modelsim/Questa

Comment: Unfortunately don't have access to, so I'm going to continue with Incisive for now, thanks again